# How to increase/decrese brightness in smaller values?

Tags: monitors, brightness

Is there a way I can decrease or increase my monitor brightness level in smaller percentage values (like 1% or 2%) rather than 5% on Linux Mint? Also, I would the fix to work with my function keys as well. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (for brightness decrease) and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (for brightness increase).

Here is my `inxi -Fxzr` report-

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.5.0-17-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: Cinnamon 6.0.4 Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82K2 v: IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ACH6
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0T76486 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: H3CN45WW(V3.03)
    date: 09/01/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 25.6 Wh (59.5%) condition: 43.0/45.0 Wh (95.6%)
    volts: 11.9 min: 11.5
    model: 0x53 0x4D 0x50 0x00 0x32 0x30 0x4C 0x32 0x30 0x4D 0x33 0x50 0x43
    status: Not charging
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 0 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 3 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1768 high: 4031 min/max: 400/4280 cores: 1: 400 2: 400
    3: 2246 4: 400 5: 2397 6: 400 7: 1693 8: 2847 9: 4031 10: 400 11: 2096
    12: 3907 bogomips: 79054
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] vendor: Lenovo
    driver: nvidia v: 545.29.06 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-2: AMD Cezanne vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel
    bus-ID: 05:00.0
  Device-3: IMC Networks Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-3:3
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: amdgpu,ati,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa
    gpu: amdgpu resolution: 3072x1728~120Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: RENOIR (renoir LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.54 6.5.0-17-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 05:00.1
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A bus-ID: 05:00.5
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 05:00.6
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-17-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 2000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: MEDIATEK MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Lenovo driver: mt7921e v: kernel bus-ID: 03:00.0
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-4:4
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 13.56 GiB (2.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZALQ512HBLU-00BL2
    size: 476.94 GiB temp: 27.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 31.79 GiB used: 12.73 GiB (40.0%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 35.7 MiB (14.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
  ID-3: /home size: 59.28 GiB used: 817.1 MiB (1.3%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 7.45 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p8
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 43.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 2321
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/apandada1-brightness-controller-jammy.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/apandada1-brightness-controller-jammy.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb https://mirrors.nxtgen.com/linuxmint-mirror/packages virginia main upstream import backport
    2: deb https://mirrors.nxtgen.com/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb https://mirrors.nxtgen.com/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb https://mirrors.nxtgen.com/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
Info:
  Processes: 322 Uptime: 2h 32m Memory: 13.49 GiB used: 2.21 GiB (16.4%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  inxi: 3.3.13
```

I've tried the following workarounds-

1. **ddcutil** doesn't work as I am on a laptop.
2. **Brightness Controller application**, but it is very inconvenient and doesn't work with function keys.
3. **Brightness and gamma applet**, decrease brightness works fine but increase is glitchy. So had to discard this one aswell.

I also cross-posted this question on the linux-mint forum and also subreddits like r/linux4noobs and r/linuxmint-

Linux Mint Forum - [link](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=413707)

r/linux4noobs - [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/1aoxk19/how_to_increasedecrese_brightness_in_smaller/)

r/linuxmint - [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/1ao5kdy/brightness_can_only_be_set_in_5_intervals/)